# hiberante hbm2ddl create property not works

Tags: hibernate

hi i have a simple UserDetails class  with @entity annotation and in my hibernate config file, the hbm2ddl is set to create but when running it shows the table UserDetails not exist. After I created the table it works fine. Why hibernate don't create table automatically even hbm2ddl is set to create?
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shammu</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>


        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NocacheProvider</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl">create</property>

        <mapping class="org.shammu.UserDetails" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: show us your hibernate config file here

Comment: added my config file pls ref

Comment: It think you need: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = create.
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do

Answer (score 1):

Update the below properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Refer below for all the properties:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong property name. 
Make it

property name="hbm2ddl.auto"